# FB "like button" on website and FB page, finding different number of "likes"

Tags: html, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

My site has a like button on the webpage itself, and obviously a like counter on its Facebook page. These counters are both different, and no matter how I dig through Facebook's developer pages, I can't find a way to merge them.

If I add href="Facebook.com/myPage" to the "like button" parameters, the counter on the my website displays the count from the Facebook page.

Is there eany way to merge these two counters, or at least keep the bigger one (the counter on my site without the href).

Comment: Same question asked here too FYI: http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/9984330/merging-a-websites-likes-into-a-facebook-page (Though yours came first, the other one is a bit clearer IMHO.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are using the "Like Button" and should be using the "Like Box".

"The Facebook Like Box connects directly with your Facebook Fan Page. If your website user clicks the like button within your Facebook Like Box, that will add to the total number of likes you have on your Facebook Fan Page." (from Read it here: http://www.eprcreations.com/how-do-i-connect-the-facebook-likes-on-my-website-with-my-facebook-fan-page-likes/)

You can generate the Like Box here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/